# can't access backbone collection through object notation

Tags: object, collections, backbone.js

I've got a backbone model with contains a collection. 
The output from the console when I do `console.log(this.model)` is

```
d
_changed: false
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
cid: "c1"
id: 63
itemlist: d
  _byCid: Object
  _byId: Object
  _onModelEvent: function () { [native code] }
  _removeReference: function () { [native code] }
  length: 5
  models: Array[5]
  __proto__: o
url: "user/63"
__proto__: o
```

perfect! now, I want to get the `itemlist` collection so I can do `this.model.itemlist.each(render(item))`.

But when I try to output `console.log(this.model.itemlist)`, I get an empty collection

```
d
 _byCid: Object
 _byId: Object
 _callbacks: Object
 _onModelEvent: function () { [native code] }
 _removeReference: function () { [native code] }
 length: 0
 models: Array[0]
 parent: d
 __proto__: o
```

I'm not sure why this is, when I output the model, I can see the nested collection. why can't I get to the collection? or how can I get to the collection.

I create the nested collection via

```
user.fetch({
    success: function(response){
              user.itemlist = new itemlistcollection(response.items)
       }
});
```

----------------- update -----------------

as @Paul help me to discover, the views are being triggered before the fetch function is completing, so I have the collection when I output from the `fetch`, but I don't have the collection available int he view, which is where it is needed.

The fetch action is occuring in my router, I've created a function to initialize the object if it hasn't already been initialized (not sure how others to this. My router looks like this

```
User.Router = Backbone.Router.extend ({
     routes: {

        "user/new":  "newUser",
        "user/:id":  "userView"
        "":             "index"
    },

    re_initialize: function(id){
           user.fetch({
              success: function(response){
              user.itemlist = new itemlistcollection(response.items)
             }
          });
      },

       userView: function(){

       console.log(user.itemlist);
       new User.View(user);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a race condition since `fetch` is an asynchronous method.

Have you confirmed `fetch` has processed the request from the server before you call `this.model.itemList`?

To confirm this, add a console log message in the fetch method

```
user.fetch({
  success: function(response){
    user.itemlist = new itemlistcollection(response.items)
    console.log(user.itemList)
  }
});
```

UPDATE

If you want the view to render the collection after it has been fetched, you trigger a 'fetched' event on your model, and have the view bind to this event to render the collection.

Here is an example of how you can update your code

```
user.fetch({
  success: function(response){
    user.itemList = new itemlistcollection(response.items);
    user.trigger('fetched');
  }
});

yourView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('fetched', this.renderList, this);
  },

  renderList: function() {
    this.model.itemList.each(render(item));
  }
}
```

Comment: it appears you may be correct Paul, though the problem isn't within the fetch, when I output the statement as above, I get the list properly. It appears the problem is that the route is triggering the views before the fetch is processed. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, your response lead me not only to the answer to this question, but also to an imporoved structure for my backbone overall. Cheers.